# how to merge local database with remote database automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ruby, database, remote-server

I have background of ruby on rails , cakephp , angular , wordpress kind of technology, currently i have a client who is asking for application which can work offline without internet, and when it got connectivity of internet the database of local server need to be automatically merge with remote database. 
can ruby-desktop will handle this kind of application , or should i go with another technology ?
which technology will make my work easy?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server you can use [Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication) for this.  Or you code your application to handle the synchronization, writing to a local database, detecting when you have connectivity, and copying data back and forth to the central database.

The choice really comes down to how many tables need to be synced, whether you have bi-directional tables, and whether you need automatic conflict detection and resolution.

So, if you have only a few tables to replicate, and they are all either download-only, or upload-only then just write this as part of your application.

Comment: there will be 2-3 table which will sync with remote table. i would like to code my application. Which language will make easy to make this?
i see that there are several framework for desktop app development in ruby language. so i am confused that which framework should i go for or should i go with Java swing for developing Desktop app?

Comment: I would use C# and Entity Framework, and have no opinion about Ruby or Java desktop UI frameworks.